# Some wedge product calculation

Tags: differential-geometry

I was just wondering, if we have some $k-$form $a$, and $n-$form $b$, then is it true that:

$$d(a\wedge b)=da\wedge b$$
Not;
$$d(a\wedge b)=da\wedge db$$

Furthermore is it also true that if $a$ is some $k$-form defined on a manifold $M$ with dimension $2m$, then $a^k=0$ $\forall k>m?$ It says this is true, but I do not get the operation $a^k$, what does it mean for a differential form to the $k$th square mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither, if $a$ is a $k$-form and $b$ any form, then
$$d(a\wedge b)=da\wedge b+(-1)^ka\wedge db.$$

Comment: However if $ b$ was closed then what I asked would hold? I further edited my question.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis Yes, your question has become **two** questions. Of course, $a^2=a\wedge a$, $a^3=a\wedge a\wedge a$ etc.

Comment: But I do not get why it is specifically 0 under that condition?

Comment: @AuroraBorealis for large $k$ the degree of $a^m$ exceeds the dimension of the manifold.

Comment: Could we show algebraically show that it is $0?$ I get your point intuitively speaking, but it doesn't convince me enough, I will appreciate further assistance.